# Code sign key, erro na keychain

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, mac, xamarin.ios

Eu sou novo na área de programação e iOS e gostaria de entender o que é esse erro e entender como posso arrumá-lo.

> Error: iOS code signing key 'iPhone Developer: Luiz ***** (F*********)' not found in keychain. (N***App.iOS)

Já tentei ler vários fóruns e tudo mais.

Não achei nada pra Visual Studio para Mac.

Comment: Você já tinha desenvolvido algo ou é a primeira vez que tenta?

Comment: É a primeira vez que estou mechendo com iOS e com o Visual Studio. Isso influencia muito??

Comment: Este erro ocorre em que momento, exatamente?

Comment: Acho que seria interessante descreve melhor como o projeto está configurado e os passos que você está realizando. Ou se for o caso um trecho de código. Isso pode ajudar a entender o problema.

Comment: Isso ocorre quando tento rodar o projeto dentro do iphone da empresa. Quando temto usar o emulador no vs ele roda o aplicativo normalmente.. Sem erros

Comment: Acho que vale a pena comentar tambem que esse Luiz, era da empresa que estava encarregada do aplicativo. Agora esta sobre meus cuidados, mas não consigo emular ele no app aqui da emrpesa.

Comment: @GabeFernandes Vocês têm uma conta de developer da Apple? Ela está configurada no XCode?

Comment: @Victor, se possível evite fazer estas edições que só movem o conteúdo de um lado para o outro. Me parece que sua edição não melhorou absolutamente nada. Além de que, seguindo os guias de formatação, a palavra iOS não deveria ser monoespaçada.

Comment: ok, não irei mais editar perguntas.

Comment: Tenho, mas eu não sei como editar.. Eu tenho ideia que tenho que colocar minha conta em algum lugar, mas onde é uma excelente pergunta..